# unable to convert number to words from Pandas series using num2words python library

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am unable to make a new column in pandas dataframe which converts a number to words using python num2words library, its working using simple int or float parameters but not working with series

This is what i have tried:

```
data['words'] = data['Value'].apply(lambda row : num2words(row['Value']))
```

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>   ----> 1 data['words'] = data['Value'].apply(lambda row : num2words(row['Value']))
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
>      4040             else:
>      4041                 values = self.astype(object).values
>   -> 4042                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
>      4043 
>      4044         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):
>
> pandas_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()
>
> in (row)
>   ----> 1 data['words'] = data['Value'].apply(lambda row : num2words(row['Value']))
>
> TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: this is not how to use apply. It should look sth like this `data['words'] = data['Value'].apply(num2words)`

Comment: Since you're calling `apply` on `data['Value']`, what gets passed to your lambda is the current column item, _not_ a complete row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can accomplish this is by defining a simple function that takes `row` as input and returns `num2words(row['Value'])`.

Then you can apply it on the DataFrame with `axis=1`.

```
def f(row):
    return num2words(row['Value'])

data['words'] = data.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Or you can apply directly to the column.

```
data['words'] = data['Value'].apply(num2words)
```